# Is it possible to navigate swf file using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

When we open plain swf in browser, we are able to control the swf file by right clicking, the available control are: zoom in, zoom out, quality, rewind (previous frame), forward (next frame), and print. Is it possible to trigger those control using javascript especially jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should be able to do this as along as the swf file is under your control (not 3rd party produced). You should be able to implement a few extra methods inside the swf-file which do what you want and then just call those using the [ExternalInterface](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15683.html). This links shows a few samples you can google the rest of the information you need yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is not possible with JavaScript. But, you can try this [Custom Right Click Menu](http://www.bezzmedia.com/swfspot/tutorials/flash8/Custom_Right_Click_Menu)